# Kingston A400 M.2 SSD doesn't show up in BIOS in Aorus Motherboard

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, motherboard

I was building my first PC gamer by my one with motherboard **Aorus B360M Gaming 3 (rev 1.0)** and everything worked out fine, except for my **M.2 Sata Kingston A400 480gb SSD**. I freaked out because I don't know what to do, the SSD just don't show up in BIOS or Windows. I checked out in Gigabyte site and I got this link:

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B360M-AORUS-GAMING-3-rev-10/support#support-doc

In the M.2 support section I coudn't find the Kingston A400 M.2 but at the top of the document it says "Qualified Vendors List (QVL)" not something like the **only supported SSDs**...

I got two SATAs ports in use with a temporary HD(WD) and a SSD 2.5''(Crucial) and I tried updating the BIOS firmware from F11 to F14a.

Could someone please help me? I need to know if there is some BIOS setup to solve it, or if the SSD is dead or just isn't compatible..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing my VGA (it was covering the bottom M.2 Sata Slot) and plugging it in the M.2 Sata Slot..